# Find different format of a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table whose key formats are inconsistent. The key could be made up of numbers, letters and symbols e.g. '.' and '-'.

```
 [Example Primary Key]
 45-00000
 12321-AAA00
 12121-00000.123
 PPP-67898.222
```

Is there a way for me to see all the key formats in my table and select all keys based on a particular key format?

All numbers are considered identical and all letters are considered identical but symbols are considered distinct

```
[These are all different formats]
AB-123
AB.123
AB-1234
AB-AS45
12-123
12-1234

[These are identical formats]
12-1234.001
88-6655.447

[Another identical format]
1A-44SS.CDB
1Z-45AA.ABC
```

Comment: So you have letters, digits, dashes and dots? Do replace regexp, then group by.

Comment: for the record... they are horrible primary keys!

Comment: I guess they are coming from another source and that's why you have this mess. Then Tanner is right, don't let this mess control your database by making it the primary key. Provide your own primary key and store this in another column (with or without a unique index).